# Infopath Forms in Subversion

Tags: svn, infopath

Just would like to know if anyone has tried using source control for Infopath 2007 forms specifically for Subversion.  Is it advisable to upload these type of sources (not in text format) in SVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By versioning .xsn files you’re putting binary files under version control which has some drawbacks:

1. No ability to compare between versions (although SVN can compare bitmap files).
2. No ability to merge with the work of other users.

Having said that, there are still benefits:

1. You can revert work in progress at any time.
2. You can roll back to a previous revision at any time.
3. You can easily share your work with others (although you have the merge limitation mentioned above).
4. You can still store your code in a central location.

If the drawbacks are not showstoppers then I’d do it for the sake of the benefits.

BTW, remember there are plenty of other binary files often stored in SCM; bitmap images, Flash animations etc.

Comment: Thanks Troy... Indeed, this will help.
Considering the benefits enumerated, this gives a valid reason on using SVN at least for the purpose of keeping source at central location and reverting to previous versions.  Most of the time, Infopath form development is handled by one developer alone which may not have a need for merging work with other developers. Sharing for the purpose of reference will be enough for our requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The InfoPath form .xsn is a packed container format that contains a bunch of XML files and some images.

I would rather sugesst to extract the InfoPath form to source files and check them in.

You can work on source files as well as on the packed `.xsn` of course.
The source files are XML and the **history can be tracked** well by SVN.

Comment: Thanks MrFox.  I think this is the best option if the requirement involves Infopath development with custom coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add this type of data to subversion is added in octeam-sream type, next you can use subversion and administrate versions.